# Implementing Weekly RFM Segmentation from Priority ERP Data and Integrating with Email Marketing Service

Tags: marketing

I am looking for some guidance on a specific task involving RFM (Recency, Frequency, Monetary) segmentation. My current workflow involves exporting data from Priority ERP, but I need help with the following steps:

**RFM Segmentation:**
I can export the necessary data from Priority ERP, but Priority does not offer RFM segmentation functionality. I am seeking advice on how to best perform this segmentation outside of Priority, preferably on a weekly basis. What tools or methods are recommended for processing and segmenting the exported data?

**Integration with Email Marketing Service:**
Once I have created the RFM segments, I need to implement these changes into the segments within our email marketing service. Does anyone have experience or tips on the most efficient way to update these segments? We are using Flashy for our email marketing.

I am open to suggestions on software, scripts, or any process that could streamline this workflow. Any advice on automating these processes or integrating these systems more effectively would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!